# Generalization of the estimate $e^{x}\geq \dfrac{x^{n}}{n!}$

Tags: calculus, inequality, gamma-function

It follows trivially from the definition of the exponential function that for every $x>0$ and $n\geq 1$, 
$$
e^{x}\geq\frac{x^n}{n!} = \frac{x^n}{\Gamma(n+1)}.
$$
Is this inequality still true for real $n$? That is

> Let $r>3$ be a real number. Is it true that
>   $$
> e^{x}\geq \frac{x^r}{\Gamma(r+1)}
> $$
>   for every $x\geq 1$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inequality holds for $r \ge 1$ and $x \ge 0$.

According to [Pretty lower bound on the gamma function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1038957/pretty-lower-bound-on-the-gamma-function) we have
$$
\Gamma(r+1) \ge \left( \frac{r+1}{e}\right)^r \ge  \left( \frac{r}{e}\right)^r
$$
so that is suffices to show that
$$
r^r e^{-r} \ge x^r e^{-x} \, ,
$$
which is straight-forward.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $x^se^{-x}$ has a maximum w.r.t. $x$ at $x=s$, and hence it suffices to ask when we have

$$\Gamma(s+1)\stackrel?\ge s^se^{-s}=\left(\frac se\right)^s\ge x^se^{-x}$$

which is equivalent to asking when does this weak Stirling approximation give a lower bound to $\Gamma(s+1)$. A rigorous proof may be found by looking into the bounds from Laplace's method in the derivation of the Stirling approximation as shown on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#An_alternative_derivation).