# Integral with gamma function

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals, gamma-function

Inspired by the limit

$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n} = e^{-1}
$$

and using desmos.com, I plotted the function

$$
f(x)=\frac{\sqrt[x]{\Gamma(x+1)}}{x}-\frac{1}{e}
$$

and obtained the result bellow.

[image]

Don't know why, but I had the feeling that the integral

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\sqrt[x]{\Gamma(x+1)}}{x}-\frac{1}{e}\right)dx
$$

would converge. Then I used Wolfram to test it. Here's it's solution:

[image]

Using desmos.com, I started to test some values for the fraction $\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n}$ and for values greater than $n=169$, the computer can't solve, but I know that that the value will converge to $e^{-1}$, so large values of $n$ shouldn't be a problem. So the problem is the computer, which makes me think that Wolfram suffer the same type of issue.

So, is there an analytic way to prove that the integral converges? Does the integral have a closed form? If it does not converge, how can I prove it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The problem isn't the asymptotic behaviour when $x\rightarrow\infty$ but the divergence of the integrand at $x=0$.

Comment: Hi Abezhiko. Thank you for the quick answer. I've tested the same integral (using Wolfram) but with the lower bound equal to 1. Same result (divergence).

Comment: The substitution $x=1/t$ implies  
$$
\int_a^\infty\left(\frac{\Gamma(x+1)^{1/x}}{x}-\frac{1}{e}\right)\mathrm{d}x = \int_0^{1/a}\left(\frac{\Gamma\left(1+\frac{1}{t}\right)^t}{t}-\frac{1}{et^2}\right)\mathrm{d}t
$$
with $a>0$. In this form, the integrand is singular at $t=0$; so I guess that the tail of the original integrand doesn't decrease fast enough for convergence.

Comment: So basically, you are asking wheter the integral converges or diverges as $x \to \infty$ regardless of what the lower bound is, correct?

Comment: Thank you Abezhiko and Accelerator. Originally, I want to know if the total integral converges (with the interval $[0, \infty]$. And if it doesn't, the integral with the limit $[a, \infty]$ converges for all $a > 0$? And if so, is there a closed form?

Comment: There is in your own comprehension, as Abezhiko, Accelerator remarked already,  defined limit value does not imply convergent convergent integral measure along certain region. The answer to closed form is "Probably not",   without any formal implication of "probably"-adverb here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As $x\to\infty$, the integrand behaves like (using Sterling’s formula) $$\frac{\left(\sqrt{2\pi x} (x/e)^x \right)^{1/x} }{x} -\frac 1e  \\ = \frac{(2\pi x)^{\frac{1}{2x}} -1}{e} \\ = \frac{e^{\frac{\ln (2\pi x)}{2x}} -1}{e} \\ \approx  \frac{\ln (2\pi x)}{2ex}
 $$

Evidently $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\ln (2\pi x)}{2ex} dx$ diverges, so also the original integral.

Comment: Thank you, @Vishu. I'm wondering, maybe we can use  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1038957/pretty-lower-bound-on-the-gamma-function to prove the divergence.

Comment: @otreblig We sure can.

Answer (score 3):

There is also a problem around $x=0$ since
$$\log (\Gamma (x+1))=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\psi ^{(n-1)}(1)}{n!} \,x^n=-\gamma  x+\frac{\pi ^2 x^2}{12}+\frac{x^3 \psi
   ^{(2)}(1)}{6}+O\left(x^4\right)$$
$$f(x)=\frac{\sqrt[x]{\Gamma(x+1)}}{x}-\frac{1}{e}$$
$$f(x)=\color{red}{\frac{e^{-\gamma }}{x}}+\left(\frac{e^{-\gamma }}{12}  \pi
   ^2-\frac{1}{e}\right)+\frac{e^{-\gamma }}{2}  
   \left(\frac{\pi ^4}{144}+\frac{\psi
   ^{(2)}(1)}{3}\right)x+O\left(x^2\right)$$ which is a quite good approximation.

Consider
$$I_k=\int_{10^{-k}}^1 f(x)\,dx$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
k & \text{approximation}& \text{solution}\\
 1 & 1.35996 & 1.36433 \\
 2 & 2.66105 & 2.66542 \\
 3 & 3.95470 & 3.95907 \\
 4 & 5.24759 & 5.25197 \\
 5 & 6.54041 & 6.54478 \\
 6 & 7.83322 & 7.83759 \\
 7 & 9.12603 & 9.13040 \\
 8 & 10.4188 & 10.4232 \\
 9 & 11.7116 & 11.7160 \\
 10 & 13.0045 & 13.0088 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Nice but diverging.